# How to add an Anchor tag inside an already existing li tag

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is very simple, but I have struggled to find an answer.

I have created a list and I want to add the a tag inside the `<li>` tag and then `setAttribute` to that `<a>` tag using JS:

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li> <!-- This is what a have right now -->
  <li><a href="#HTML">one</a></li> <!-- This is what I want -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Rather than editing to something that still doesn't render correctly in stackoverflow, please look at the preview that appears under the large textbox to see what it will look like before you post it

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You also appear to have mistaken stackoverflow as a code-writing service. What have you done, and what are you struggling to get working?  We're not going to do it for you

Comment: Where does `#HTML` come from?

Comment: So what did you try? Where do you get the info from for the href? seems like a simple select lis, loop over, read html, createElement, setAttribute, appendChild.

Comment: You seem to be in need of an [introductory JavaScript tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) (at least to judge from the effort expressed in the question).

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";
// This first line you most probably have to change according to your context
// This get the first element of all the li tags in the whole document
const li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]
// This gets the text content ('one') of that 'li'
const tc = li.textContent
// This removes the first child content of li, which is the text
li.childNodes[0].remove()
// This will create a new 'a' element, set the href attribute, insert the text from above into it
// and that insert this 'a' into the 'li'
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.textContent = tc
a.setAttribute('href', '#HTML')
li.append(a)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there anyways to loop this or do I Have to do this for every sinlge LI item? Thanks for the answer

Comment: This depends on the overall HTML you have. Best is to give the wrapping `<ul>` tag an id and then start from there.

Comment: Maybe this example helps: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/27d690a0129cddf822974ecdc9813944?editors=1011

Answer (score -1):

```js
// select the <li>
const li = document.querySelector('li');

// create the <a>
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href='#html';
a.innerText = li.innerText;

// empty <li> and replace its content by <a>
li.innerHTML = '';
li.appendChild(a);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would suggest it's because the OP has shown no effort to solve this themselves, and the downvoter was objecting to the fact that you are doing the work for them